# ros2 run ros2: command not found

Tags: ros2

I've installed ros2 and have the talk and listen nodes working but when I try `ros2 run` it returns `ros2: command not found`

I'm sure it's something quite simple that I've missed but not sure what.

Comment: Are you trying to run `ros2 run` without anything else?

Comment: How did you install ROS 2? You may not have installed the command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm making progress now. I had to run '''source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash''' followed by '''ros2 demo_nodes_cpp talker''' It now prints the Hello World lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a ROS 2 node you need to use the following command:

`ros2 run <ros2-package> <node-executable>`

So, for example if you have the `demo_nodes_cpp` package installed you should be able to run this command on your terminal:

`ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`

And the output on the terminal should be the following:

```
[INFO] [1697323061.154074785] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1697323062.153924983] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[INFO] [1697323063.153802844] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
[INFO] [1697323064.153614182] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 4'
[INFO] [1697323065.153554085] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 5'
[INFO] [1697323066.153432457] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 6'
[INFO] [1697323067.153312557] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 7'
```